# Cannot show a message during program load on iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

During load of my application I am loading settings and other things, and want to be able to show a message to the user. However this does not work on my Delphi XE6 FireMonkey application targeting iOS (iOSSimulator).

When I call ShowMessage or MessageDlg during program load, it locks, and nothing is shown. It is probably entering the modal state, but since the message is not shown, it is not possible to continue.
Even in the main forms FormActivate, calling ShowMessage does not show anything.

How can I show a message while loading the application?

Comment: I don't know anything about Firemonkey but it sounds like you need to load settings and the other things on a separate thread

Comment: I hope to be able to show a modal message where user could answer e.g. Yes/No, which would then influence how the app is loaded, but maybe this violates how iOS is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that no one have written about this before and that no Firemonkey users have answered my question.
That you are allowed to call Showmessage during program load, but the app locks if you do it, is not appropriate behavior. In a desktop app, it is quite normal to show a message during program load, in case something fails.
I am converting a 500k line project from VCL to FMX, and since I cannot show a message on iOS, I will have to restructure the create and load code.

The solution I plan to implement is to make failsafe solutions that will allow the app to load no matter what happens, then when the app is running, I can show whatever messages have come up during load (those that the user have to consider).

If anyone have more information or suggestions for a better solution, please comment.

Comment: It seems perfectly reasonable that some function cannot be called at certain times during an application's life. Why is that so unreasonable?

Comment: Maybe because I have used VCL for too many years :-) (in VCL I could call Showmessage anytime)

Comment: Mobile is a different world though, and FMX in spite of superficial similarities is a massive change from VCL

Comment: At least it would have been better if Embarcadero had chosen to throw an exception instead of just locking the application.

Comment: That would require their code to detect that the call would fail. That might be difficult to do. The detection could fail. It would complicate their code. Very often for framework designers it is reasonable for them to push sanity checking onto the consumer of the framework. I feel strongly that they got this right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loading symbol along with Message. It will serve your purpose. You can use "MBProgressHud", you not need to give any extra effort, just pass parameter and it will display loading image along with text. Enjoy!

Comment: Isn't that control a Cocoa control?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) is a custom Xcode component. It looks great, though it will require a little work to use it in Delphi Firemonkey.

Comment: Accept the answer if it is OK.